# How do I make a part of music repeat endlessly in Rosegarden?

Tags: midi, rosegarden

I want to choose a MIDI instrument for a track in Rosegarden. I start playing the music and traverse instruments.

But the music moves on from the place where I can hear this track playing, so I need to manually rewind each time.

How do I order Roseharden to repeat from marker A to marker B?

If possible this repeat should be temporary (i.e. not saved into the music itself).

Comment: Gooooggglleeeee

Comment: @xR34P3Rx, Please suggest specific Google search request. I've tried `rosegarden repeat`, but haven't saw anything useful.

Comment: Workaround: Place a Quick Marker at the beginning of the loop, and press Ctrl+M to jump there (better than finding and clicking the position with mouse).

Answer (score 1):

" *Rosegarden allows you to highlight a period of time in the main ruler, which will be used as a "range" for editing operations and which will be looped during playback.
To set the current range, click and drag with the Shift key pressed on the subdivided area of the main ruler at the top of the editing window. The range that you drag will be highlighted in white as you drag it, and will snap to the nearest beat boundary at both ends. Any subsequent playback will then be constrained to looping this range.
You can also set a range between two markers by shift-clicking between the marker positions in the marker ruler, or set a range using the Transport window. The Transport contains small buttons to set the start and end of the current range to the current playback pointer position. Either of these methods allows you to set more precise end points for your range than you can with click-drag.
To clear a range and restore normal playback, click on the subdivided area of the main ruler with the Shift key pressed, or toggle the loop button on the Transport.
Note that playback looping when a range is defined is not the same thing as the repeating segment function available in the segment parameters (which seamlessly repeats individual segments rather than causing the transport to jump).*"

From: https://www.rosegardenmusic.com/doc/en/markers-ranges-loops.html